# SQL Query is fetching in correct data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Below is my query and the requirement details.

```
WITH    parameters    AS (
    SELECT  TO_DATE ('01-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS startdt  -- Always use 4 digits for years
    ,       TO_DATE ('30-JUN-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS enddt
    ,       'CWR'                                  AS per_org
    FROM    dual
),    got_business_unit   AS (
    SELECT  p.startdt, p.enddt
    ,       d1.emplid, d1.per_org, d1.effdt
    ,       CASE
                WHEN  b.business_unit  IS NULL
                THEN  'I'
                ELSE  d1.hr_status
            END         AS hr_status
    ,       b.business_unit
    FROM    parameters       p
    JOIN    ps_cts_job_dtl1  d1   ON  d1.per_org      = p.per_org
                                  AND d1.effdt       <= p.enddt
    OUTER APPLY (
                    SELECT  MAX (b.business_unit)  AS business_unit
                    FROM    ps_cts_job_dtl  d
                    JOIN    ps_cts_iqn_bu   b   ON  b.business_unit = d.business_unit
                    WHERE   d.emplid        = d1.emplid
                    AND     d.effdt         = d1.effdt
                )            b
)
SELECT    g.emplid
,         GREATEST ( g.effdt
                   , g.startdt
                   )  AS startdt
,         LEAST ( e.enddt
                , g.enddt
                )     AS enddt
,         g.per_org
,         g.hr_status
,         'Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table'
                   AS reason
FROM      got_business_unit  g
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT  NVL ( MIN (gs.effdt) - 1
                            , DATE '9999-12-31'
                            )  AS enddt
                FROM    got_business_unit  gs
                WHERE   gs.emplid    = g.emplid
                AND     gs.effdt     > g.effdt
                AND     gs.hr_status = 'I'
            )                e
WHERE     hr_status  = 'A'
AND       e.enddt    > g.startdt
ORDER BY  emplid
,         startdt
;
```

Query out ut as per the below Data.

```
EMPLID  STARTDT ENDDT   PER_ORG HR_STATUS   REASON
733930  1-Jun-19    3-Jun-19    CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733930  2-Jun-19    3-Jun-19    CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733930  15-Jun-19   18-Jun-19   CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733930  26-Jun-19   30-Jun-19   CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733931  6-Jun-19    9-Jun-19    CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733931  26-Jun-19   30-Jun-19   CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733931  28-Jun-19   30-Jun-19   CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
```

I want to fetch the contract employee information with `HR_Status = 'A'. ( per_org = 'CWR' in PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 table )`.
And active contract employee Business_Unit value of `PS_CTS_JOB_DTL` table should be present in `PS_CTS_IQN_BU` table.
 there is a chance to have an employee multiple consecutive rows with `hr_status='A'`

Using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Below is my "PS_CTS_JOB_DTL"  table structure and data. in this table (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ) are key fields.

- EMPL_RCD: when ever employee converted from contract to full time and from full time to contract this value will increase. (0,1,2,...)
- EFFDT: this filed use to track when change happens.
- EFFSEQ: this field will increase from 0 to 1,2 .. when there is more than one transaction in same date.( with same effdt )
- ACTION: Will determine which action they taken on employee ( please don't consider action field to achieve output as below. because action codes may different in each time)

JOB Table

```
EMPLID  BUSINESS_UNIT   EMPL_RCD    EFFDT   EFFSEQ  ACTION
733930  US410   0   27-May-19   0   ADD
733930  US410   0   02-Jun-19   0   DTA
733930  US410   0   4-Jun-19    0   TER
733930  US410   1   6-Jun-19    0   HIR
733930  US410   1   15-Jun-19   0   TER
733930  US410   2   15-Jun-19   1   ADD
733930  US608   2   19-Jun-19   0   ASC
733930  CN512   2   26-Jun-19   0   ASG
733931  US410   0   26-Apr-19   0   HIR
733931  US410   0   5-Jun-19    0   TER
733931  IN208   1   6-Jun-19    0   ADD
733931  IN208   1   10-Jun-19   0   TER
733931  IN208   2   12-Jun-19   0   HIR
733931  IN408   2   18-Jun-19   0   ASC
733931  IN408   2   19-Jun-19   0   TER
733931  IN208   3   26-Jun-19   0   ADD
733931  IN208   3   28-Jun-19   0   DTA
```

Below is my "PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1"  table structure and data. in this table (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ) are key fields.

- EMPL_RCD: when ever employee converted from contract to full time and from full time to contract this value will increase. (0,1,2,...)
- EFFDT: this filed use to track when change happens.
- EFFSEQ: this field will increase from 0 to 1,2 .. when there is more than one transaction in same date.( with same effdt )
- HR_STATUS: To identify employee status ( A = Active, I = Inactive ).
- PER_ORG: to identify employee type ( CWR = Contract, EMP = Employee )

Note: employee may contains more then one row with HR_STATUS = 'A' before he is going to inactive ( HR_STSTUS = 'I' )

```
EMPL_ID EMPL_RCD    EFFDT   EFFSEQ  HR_STATUS   PER_ORG
733930  0   27-May-19   0   A   CWR
733930  0   02-Jun-19   0   A   CWR
733930  0   4-Jun-19    0   I   CWR
733930  1   6-Jun-19    0   A   EMP
733930  1   15-Jun-19   0   I   EMP
733930  2   15-Jun-19   1   A   CWR
733930  2   19-Jun-19   0   A   CWR
733930  2   26-Jun-19   0   A   CWR
733931  0   26-Apr-19   0   A   EMP
733931  0   5-Jun-19    0   I   EMP
733931  1   6-Jun-19    0   A   CWR
733931  1   10-Jun-19   0   I   CWR
733931  2   12-Jun-19   0   A   EMP
733931  2   18-Jun-19   0   A   EMP
733931  2   19-Jun-19   0   I   EMP
733931  3   26-Jun-19   0   A   CWR
733931  3   28-Jun-19   0   A   DTA
```

Below is my "PS_CTS_IQN_BU"  table structure and data.

```
IQN BU Setp
Country Business_Unit
USA US410
USA US412
CAN CN512
IND IN208
```

Based on above three tables i need to fetch below output. When i pass from date and to date in query (month start and end dates i.e like '01-JUN-19' and '30-JUN-19' ) , query should fetch employee active from active to dates as CWR and that employee Business unit should be in PS_CTS_IQN_BU table.

Required output:

Note: Reason column for understanding, no need to display reason column

While fetching below out put Please map EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ Key fields in both JOB_DTL and JOB_DTL1  ( Map  Key fields is very important )

- Employee 733930 is active CWR in between '01-Jun-19' to '03-Jun-19' and employee have only one row with HR_STATUS ='A'  ( employee have more than one row with HR_STATUS = 'A' ) and Business_unit value present in PS_CTS_IQN_BU table.
- Employee 733930 is active CWR in between '15-Jun-19' to '18-Jun-19' and employee have only one row with HR_STATUS ='A' and Business_unit value present in PS_CTS_IQN_BU table.
- Employee 733930 is active as CWR  in between '19-JUN-19' to '25-JUN-19' in different BU which not in IQN_BU setup table, so i want to exclude that information.
- Employee 733930 is active CWR from '26-Jun-19' with HR_STATUS ='A' and Business_unit value present in PS_CTS_IQN_BU table.
- Employee 733931 is active CWR from '06-Jun-19' to '09-Jun-19' and, employee have only one row with HR_STATUS ='A' and Business_unit value present in PS_CTS_IQN_BU table.
- Employee 733931 is active CWR from '26-Jun-19' to '30-Jun-19' and he is having more than one row with HR_STATUS = 'A' and Business_unit value present in PS_CTS_IQN_BU table.

```
EMPLID  FROM_DATE   To_DATE PER_ORG HR_STATUS   Reason
733930  1-Jun-19    3-Jun-19    CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733930  15-Jun-19   18-Jun-19   CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733930  26-Jun-19   30-Jun-19   CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733931  6-Jun-19    9-Jun-19    CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
733931  26-Jun-19   30-JUN-19   CWR A   Employee is active as CWR and BU is in IQN_BU setup table
```

PS_CTS_JOB_DTL Table Build and Insert Scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID VARCHAR2(11) NOT NULL,  
   BUSINESS_UNIT VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,  
   EMPL_RCD INT NOT NULL,  
   EFFDT DATE,  
   EFFSEQ INT NOT NULL,  
   ACTION VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL) ;  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733930','US410',0,to_date('27-MAY-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'ADD');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733930','US410',0,to_date('02-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'DTA');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733930','US410',0,to_date('04-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'TER');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733930','US410',1,to_date('06-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'HIR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733930','US410',1,to_date('15-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'TER');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733930','US410',2,to_date('15-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),1,'ADD');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733930','US608',2,to_date('19-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'ASC');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733930','CN512',2,to_date('26-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'ASG');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','US410',0,to_date('26-APR-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'HIR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','US410',0,to_date('05-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'TER');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','IN208',1,to_date('06-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),1,'ADD');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','IN208',1,to_date('10-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'TER');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','IN208',2,to_date('12-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'HIR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','IN408',2,to_date('18-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'ASC');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','IN408',2,to_date('19-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'TER');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','IN208',3,to_date('26-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'ADD');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL (EMPLID,BUSINESS_UNIT,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,ACTION) values ('733931','IN208',3,to_date('28-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'DTA');   
PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 Table Build and Insert Scripts:



CREATE TABLE PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID VARCHAR2(11) NOT NULL,  
   EMPL_RCD INT NOT NULL,  
   EFFDT DATE,  
   EFFSEQ INT NOT NULL,  
   HR_STATUS VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,  
   PER_ORG VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL) ;  


Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733930',0,to_date('27-MAY-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733930',0,to_date('02-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733930',0,to_date('04-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'I','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733930',1,to_date('06-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','EMP');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733930',1,to_date('15-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'I','EMP');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733930',2,to_date('15-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),1,'A','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733930',2,to_date('19-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733930',2,to_Date('26-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',0,to_date('26-APR-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','EMP');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',0,to_date('05-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'I','EMP');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',1,to_date('06-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',1,to_date('10-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'I','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',2,to_date('12-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','EMP');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',2,to_date('18-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','EMP');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',2,to_date('19-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'I','EMP');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',3,to_date('26-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','CWR');  
Insert into PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1 (EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,EFFSEQ,HR_STATUS,PER_ORG) values ('733931',3,to_date('28-JUN-19','DD-MON-YY'),0,'A','CWR');  
 PS_CTS_IQN_BU Table Build and Insert Scripts: ( IQN business unit setup ) 



CREATE TABLE PS_CTS_IQN_BU (COUNTRY VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,  
   BUSINESS_UNIT VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL) ;  
Insert into PS_CTS_IQN_BU (COUNTRY,BUSINESS_UNIT) values ('USA','US410');  
Insert into PS_CTS_IQN_BU (COUNTRY,BUSINESS_UNIT) values ('USA','US412');  
Insert into PS_CTS_IQN_BU (COUNTRY,BUSINESS_UNIT) values ('CAN','CN512');  
Insert into PS_CTS_IQN_BU (COUNTRY,BUSINESS_UNIT) values ('IND','IN208');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be close to solution, everything you need is to group consecutive ranges. Because you use Oracle 12 and `outer apply`, I cannot correct your original query (I have 11g). So I wrote something similar:

```
with 
  par(sdt, edt, unit) as (select date '2019-06-01', date '2019-06-30', 'CWR' from dual),
  t1 as (
    select emplid, empl_rcd, effdt fd, effseq, d1.hr_status, d1.per_org, 
           lead(effdt) over (partition by emplid order by effdt) td,
           (select max(business_unit) keep (dense_rank last order by effdt)
             from ps_cts_job_dtl d 
             where d.emplid = d1.emplid and d.effdt <= d1.effdt) bu
      from ps_cts_job_dtl1 d1 ),
  t2 as (
    select emplid, greatest(fd, sdt) fd, nvl(td, edt) td, per_org, hr_status, bu
      from t1 
      join par on fd <= edt and (sdt <= td or td is null)
      where per_org = unit and hr_status = 'A' 
        and bu in (select business_unit from ps_cts_iqn_bu))
select emplid, min(fd), max(td), per_org, hr_status
  from (
    select emplid, fd, td, per_org, hr_status, 
           sum(flg) over (partition by emplid order by fd, td) grp
      from (
        select emplid, fd, td, per_org, hr_status, 
               case when lag(td) over(partition by emplid order by fd, td) >= fd 
                    then 0 else 1 
               end flg
          from t2))
  group by emplid, per_org, hr_status, grp
  order by emplid, min(fd)
```

Result for your data:

```
EMPLID      MIN(FD)     MAX(TD)     PER_ORG HR_STATUS
----------- ----------- ----------- ------- ---------
733930      2019-06-01  2019-06-04  CWR     A
733930      2019-06-15  2019-06-19  CWR     A
733930      2019-06-26  2019-06-30  CWR     A
733931      2019-06-06  2019-06-10  CWR     A
733931      2019-06-26  2019-06-30  CWR     A
```

Here, in `t1` I used subquery for business unit. `t2` eliminates unwanted rows (date range, not `CWR`, not active). Last select detects if remaining date ranges overlaps, assigns groups to rows and aggregates.

There are some problems / incosistences which makes answer hard. In your listing for `PS_CTS_JOB_DTL1` last row is:

```
733931  3   28-Jun-19   0   A   DTA
```

while in provided `inserts` it is `CWR`. And dates are more problematic, because sometimes you substract `1` from start / end date, sometimes not, and that pattern is not quite clear.

At first please try to use your query and group ranges like I did. Hope this helps.

---

> Employee 733930 is inactive on 04-JUN-2019 so I want to display from
>   01-JUN-19 to 03-JUN-19. Could you please change the query to exclude
>   inactive day.

Add `lead(hr_status) over (partition by emplid order by effdt)`, when this value equals `I` then decrement end_date:

```
with 
  par(sdt, edt, unit) as (select date '2019-06-01', date '2019-06-30', 'CWR' from dual),
  t1 as (
    select emplid, empl_rcd, effdt fd, effseq, d1.hr_status, d1.per_org, 
           lead(effdt) over (partition by emplid order by effdt) td,
           lead(hr_status) over (partition by emplid order by effdt) lst,
           (select max(business_unit) keep (dense_rank last order by effdt)
             from ps_cts_job_dtl d 
             where d.emplid = d1.emplid and d.effdt <= d1.effdt) bu
      from ps_cts_job_dtl1 d1 ),
  t2 as (
    select emplid, greatest(fd, sdt) fd, per_org, hr_status, bu, 
           nvl(case lst when 'I' then td - 1 else td end, edt) td
      from t1 
      join par on fd <= edt and (sdt <= td or td is null)
      where per_org = unit and hr_status = 'A' 
        and bu in (select business_unit from ps_cts_iqn_bu))
select emplid, min(fd), max(td), per_org, hr_status
  from (
    select emplid, fd, td, per_org, hr_status, 
           sum(flg) over (partition by emplid order by fd, td) grp
      from (
        select emplid, fd, td, per_org, hr_status, 
               case when lag(td) over(partition by emplid order by fd, td) >= fd 
                    then 0 else 1 
               end flg
          from t2))
  group by emplid, per_org, hr_status, grp
  order by emplid, min(fd);
```

Result:

```
EMPLID      MIN(FD)     MAX(TD)     PER_ORG HR_STATUS
----------- ----------- ----------- ------- ---------
733930      2019-06-01  2019-06-03  CWR     A
733930      2019-06-15  2019-06-19  CWR     A
733930      2019-06-26  2019-06-30  CWR     A
733931      2019-06-06  2019-06-09  CWR     A
733931      2019-06-26  2019-06-30  CWR     A
```

Comment: Hi @ponder Stibbons, There is a chance to employee may have more than one row with HR_STATUS = 'A' between his active start date and inactive date. so 28-JUN-19 row is extra row and action is data change, when pay changes, department changes, manager changes there will be row with HR_STATUS = 'A'.  And your query is fetching inactive day as well, I want to exclude inactive day. Employee 733930 is inactive on 04-JUN-2019 so I want to display from 01-JUN-19 to 03-JUN-19. Could you please change the query to exclude inactive day.

Comment: Hi @Ponder Stibbons, For Employee 733930 is moved to another business on 19-JUN-2019 and his business unit is not available in IQN BU table , sow I need to display start date as 15-JUN-2019 and end date as 18-JUN-2019. except this every thing is fine, could you please change your query to fetch 18-JUN-2019 instead of 19-JUN-2019  for second row.

Comment: Hi @Ponder Stibbons, For Employee 733930 is moved to another business on 19-JUN-2019 and his business unit is not available in IQN BU table , sow I need to display start date as 15-JUN-2019 and end date as 18-JUN-2019. except this every thing is fine, could you please change your query to fetch 18-JUN-2019 instead of 19-JUN-2019 for second row.

Comment: This is why I said that it is unclear when you use date or date-1. Looks like we don't need `lead()` in first subquery, just use `td-1` always. Please check this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9d6d84ed670f03c4cc47bd8be20c7d76).